# memset throwing segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, memset

I am having some problem with writing a function to extract strings from a file as part of a bigger program. Everything seems to be working fine, except when I use memset or bzero to erase the character arrays I have been using.  I have been sitting with this problem for more than an hour and I keep getting seg faults whatever I do. I am getting this error for both bzero and memset. Please help me out.
I am attaching my code below. The statement "Come out of addfront" is printed but none of the "Done with all bzero" statements are printing. I get a segmentation fault at that point. Thank you

```
void extractFileData(FILE *fp , char clientName[])
{
    char tempFileName[50], tempFilePath[100], tempFileSize[50];
    struct stat fileDetails;

    while(fgets(tempFileName, sizeof(tempFileName), fp)!= NULL)
    {
        if((newLinePos = strchr(tempFileName, '\n')) != NULL)
        {
            *newLinePos = '\0';
        }

        strcat(tempFilePath, "SharedFiles/");
        strcat(tempFilePath, tempFileName);

        if(stat(tempFilePath, &fileDetails) < 0)
        {
            perror("Stat error");
            exit(1);
        }

        //Copy it into a string
        sprintf(tempFileSize, "%zu", fileDetails.st_size);
        printf("temp file size: %s\n", tempFileSize);

        //Add all these details to the file list by creating a new node
        addFront(tempFileName, tempFileSize, clientName);

        printf("Come out of addfront\n");

        memset(&tempFileName, 0, 45);
        printf("Done with all bzero\n");
        memset(&tempFileSize, 0, sizeof(tempFileSize));
        memset(&tempFilePath, 0, sizeof(tempFilePath));

        printf("Done with all bzero\n");
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
void addFront(char fileName[], char fileSize[], char clientName[])
{
    FILENODE* n;
    printf("Inside add front function\n");
    strcpy(n->fileName, fileName);
    printf("n->filename: %s\n", n->fileName);
    strcpy(n->fileSize, fileSize);
    printf("n->filesize: %s\n", n->fileSize);
    strcpy(n->ownerName, clientName);
    printf("n->ownername: %s\n", n->ownerName);
    myFileList.head = n;
    printf("Did it go past myfilelist head = n\n");
    myFileList.numOfNodes++;
    printf("num of nodes: %d\n", myFileList.numOfNodes);
}
```

I have added my code for the addFront function. It basically adds
the details to a struct `myFileList` which is basically an implementation
of a linked list. The `FILENODE` represents each entry in the list.

EDIT:

Adding the structs I am using

```
 struct fileNode
 {
      char fileName[50];
      char fileSize[50];
          char ownerName[25];
      struct fileNode* next;
 };

 struct fileList
 {
      struct fileNode* head;
      struct fileNode* tail;
       int numOfNodes;
 };

 typedef struct fileList FILELIST;
 typedef struct fileNode FILENODE;
```

Comment: What does addFront do? BTW: when you do `strcat(tempFilePath, "SharedFiles/");` tempFilePath is not initialised. The may or may not be a \0 in there somewhere.

Comment: BTW: you should avoid strcat as much as possible. My advise is to combine the two strcat() calls into one `ret = snprintf(tempFilePath, sizeof tempFilePath,"%s/%s", "SharedFiles", tempFileName);` call.

Comment: Your `strcat` is indeed bad. But there's no language-level reason your code can crash on those `memset`s. If it really does, the only possibility I see is that `addFront` somehow destroyed the program stack structure, still allowing it to successfully return to your function, but causing it to crash on the first `memset`.

Comment: How about the uninitialised tempFilePath + the subsequent strcat() ? Damage may already have been done even before the mysterious addFront() is called.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments/inputs. The `tempFilePath` seems to be working fine since I tested by printing it out before passing it to the `stat()` call. Since the `stat()` call works fine, I guess `tempFilePath`, atleast at that point, seems to be okay. But I will make sure I change it to avoid the problems that all of you have mentioned regarding using `strcat` on uninitialized variable.

Comment: @update: n is uninitialised, it could point to anywhere. Bingo!

Comment: @wildplasser But I thought since I was using a pointer, it was not necessary to initialize it. Do you mean to say I must make it point to a new `FILENODE` before I assign it values? Also, all the `printf` statements work and the `addFront()` function successfully completes. I get the seg fault error only when it reaches the `memset` call.

Comment: `FILENODE* n;` introduces a pointer variable (probably to some struct type), but **does not initialise it** to a sane value. The subsequent `strcat(n->something, "Bogus");` will write into a random memory location. BTW: every usable compiler would issue a warning on this kind of coding error.

Comment: @wildplasser I did not know that. Also one of the reasons is I do not know how to initialize a pointer to a struct in C. I am new to C and am used to C++ where we use `new` to initialize a pointer of some type. I will work on that also. Thanks

Comment: It is not very different from a non-pointer variable. The line `int i;` allocates an int, but does not give it a value. The line `somestruct *p;` allocates a pointer (to somestruct), but does not give it a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why your program would crash there.  But I can another error in the program.  Fix the other error first, see if you still have problems.

This is **wrong**:

```
strcat(tempFilePath, "SharedFiles/");
strcat(tempFilePath, tempFileName);
```

The `tempFilePath` variable is uninitialized.  This may *coincidentally* not crash, but you cannot rely on it not to crash.  It may scribble on your stack.

Do this instead:

```
snprintf(tempFilePath, sizeof(tempFilePath), "SharedFiles/%s", tempFileName);
```

Finally, there is no need to zero the arrays.  The contents of the arrays are not used in the next loop iteration, so you might as well ignore them.

```
void extractFileData(FILE *fp , char clientName[])
{
    char tempFileName[50], tempFilePath[100], *newLinePos;
    struct stat fileDetails;
    while (fgets(tempFileName, sizeof(tempFileName), fp)) {
        if ((newLinePos = strchr(tempFileName, '\n')))
            *newLinePos = '\0';
        snprintf(tempFilePath, sizeof(tempFilePath),
                 "SharedFiles/%s", tempFileName);
        if (stat(tempFilePath, &fileDetails) < 0) {
            perror("Stat error");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("temp file size: %zu\n", tempFileSize);
        addFront(tempFileName, tempFileSize, clientName);
    }
}
```

The `snprintf()` function is really the number one choice for doing work like this in C.  It's easy to write code with `snprintf()` that "obviously won't crash", as opposed to code that "won't obviously crash".

If your code still crashes, there is an error somewhere else.

Comment: I will implement that and get back to you.

Comment: You may want to check the return value from snprintf(). It is not crucial, but it might help.

Comment: I changed my code to use `snprintf` instead of `strcat` like you suggested. I still have the same segmentation fault.
@wildplasser Did that also. It is fine

Comment: @Since I replaced the `strcat` with `snprintf` like Dietric Epp said, I don't actually need to zero the arrays since the values will get overwritten. So right now I have solved the problem by removing the memset statements and everything works as expected. But I still can't understand why memset gives me a seg fault at that point.

Comment: Well, actually my snprintf() suggestion came first. WRT memset(): that is the secret of undefined behaviour, *anything* can happen. At any moment. It is like the Spanish inquisition!

Comment: @wildplasser Sorry, I forgot to mention your first suggestion :(. 
LoL -> Spanish Inquisition commment

Comment: @wildplasser: The Spanish Inquisition gave 30 days notice for defendants to prepare their cases.

Answer (score 0):

`addFront()` needs a `n = malloc( sizeof *n)` before you do anything with it.

Comment: Plus: the pointers inside the structure need to be set to a usable value, too. (I don't even know if it are pointers, it is a very secret struct, somehow)

Comment: @wildplasser: great point, the assignment is using addresses on the stack that are useless once the function returns.

Comment: @wildplasser there is nothing secret about the structs I am using. I just did not want to add extra information which may not be useful for solving the problem.

Comment: So, it are arrays inside the struct. (but there is no struct involved, only an uninitialised pointer to a non-existing struct)

Comment: @tomlogic I am using `n = malloc(sizeof *n)` now and everything is working smoothly now. Thanks